# Feed Forward vs Convolutional Neural Network on Periodic function

Tags: self-study, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

This question is related to a homework assignment, and I am trying to get a more broad view on the question. At first glance, I find this question a little strange and I'm wondering if there is some insight I'm missing here. Specifically, I am being asked to compare the training of a fully connected FFNN and CNN to an RNN on data points generated from a sine wave.

What I know is that the nature of any type of FFNN does not lend itself to learning a periodic function. When trained, the network will fail to make proper predictions outside of the range it was trained on.

What I find strange about this question is how a fully connected or convolutional neural network would differ in this task. It seems to me like having multiple convolutional filters would not help prediction in any way, so the CNN would just degenerate to a strange form of a non-fully connected FFNN.

Maybe this degeneration is the comparison the professor is looking for and I'm reading too much into the question, but if there is something here I am missing I would appreciate some insight.